# SQL Server security issue CREATE LOGIN with user in the securityadmin role

Tags: sql-server

I have a database I've created for a client. I want the client to have users that are designated "User Admins," who have special permissions to manage user permissions in the database.

I've created a database role that has permissions to run this procedure:

```
USE [TheDatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [usradm].[udp_AddUpdateUser]    Script Date: 3/6/2023 8:14:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Description: This creates a login (if it does not exist) and assigns the appropriate roles.
--              @UserLogin should be DOMAIN\LOGINNAME
--              RoleIDs is a comma-delimited string (i.e. '1,3,4'), of IDs from the local StaffRoles table.
--              If RoleIDs includes the UserAdmin role, it also adds the user to the server securityadmin and db_securityadmin role.
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [usradm].[udp_AddUpdateUser]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StaffID int=0 OUTPUT,
    @UserLogin varchar(100),
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @RoleIDs varchar(50),
    @IsActive bit=1
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @ThisDatabase varchar(50) = 'TheDatabase'
    DECLARE @TblRoleIDs TABLE (RoleID int)

    PRINT 'Checking UserLogin'
    -- Create login if it does not exist
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.server_principals WHERE name = @UserLogin)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Creating UserLogin'
        SET @sql = 'use master;
            CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH  
            DEFAULT_DATABASE = ' + QUOTENAME(@ThisDatabase) + ',
            DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english];'
        PRINT @sql
        EXEC(@sql)
    END

    -- Create database user if it does not exist
    SET @sql = 'use ' + @ThisDatabase + ';'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    PRINT 'Checking database user'
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [type] = 'U' AND [name] = @UserLogin)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Creating database user'
        SET @sql = 'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ' FROM LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ';'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END

    -- Update user in the staff table if exists. Otherwise, add user to the Staff table
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Staff] WHERE StaffID = @StaffID)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Adding record to Staff table'
        DECLARE @IDs TABLE (ID INT);

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Staff] (FirstName, LastName, IsActive) 
        OUTPUT inserted.StaffID INTO @IDs 
        VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @IsActive)

        SELECT @StaffID = ID FROM @IDs;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Adding record to Staff table'
        UPDATE [dbo].[Staff] 
        SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, IsActive = @IsActive
        WHERE StaffID = @StaffID
    END
    
    -- Add user to StaffUsernames
    PRINT 'Adding record to StaffUsernames'
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StaffUsernames] (StaffID, UserName)
    SELECT @StaffID, @UserLogin
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[StaffUsernames] WHERE StaffID = @StaffID AND UserName = @UserLogin)

    -- Set roles
    -- First parse @RoleIDs into a table of RoleIDs.
    PRINT 'Parsing @RoleIDs into table'
    INSERT INTO @TblRoleIDs (RoleID)
    SELECT CAST(value AS int) FROM string_split(@RoleIDs,',')

    -- Add all passed RoleIDs to the StaffRoles table for this new user
    PRINT 'Adding StaffRoles'
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[StaffRoles] (StaffID, UserRoleID)
    SELECT @StaffID, RoleID
    FROM @TblRoleIDs
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[StaffRoles] WHERE StaffID = @StaffID AND UserRoleID = RoleID)

    -- Remove any existing records from the StaffRoles table for this staff member, if the RoleID is not in the passed list.
    PRINT 'Deleting StaffRoles not passed'
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[StaffRoles]
    WHERE StaffID = @StaffID AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblRoleIDs WHERE RoleID = UserRoleID)

    -- Load the list of any existing server and database roles this person has
    DECLARE @TblServerRoles table (RoleName varchar(128))
    DECLARE @TblDbRoles table (RoleName varchar(128))

    PRINT 'Loading existing server roles'
    INSERT INTO @TblServerRoles (RoleName)
    SELECT CAST(r.name AS varchar(128)) AS RoleName
    FROM master.sys.server_principals r
    INNER JOIN master.sys.server_role_members rm ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id AND r.type = 'R'
    INNER JOIN master.sys.server_principals m ON m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
    WHERE m.name = @UserLogin

    SET @sql = 'use ' + @ThisDatabase + ';'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    PRINT 'Loading existing database roles'
    INSERT INTO @TblDbRoles (RoleName)
    SELECT r.[name] AS RoleName
    FROM sys.database_principals r 
    INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members rm ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals m ON rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
    WHERE m.[name] = @UserLogin

    SELECT * FROM @TblServerRoles
    SELECT * FROM @TblDbRoles

    -- Drop user from SecurityAdmin role on the server, if udr_UserAdmin isn't in the list and they're a member of SecurityAdmin.
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblRoleIDs urids WHERE RoleID = 2) AND EXISTS (SELECT RoleName FROM @TblServerRoles WHERE RoleName = 'securityadmin')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Dropping SecurityAdmin role if it was removed'
        SET @sql = 'use master;EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember @loginame = ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ', @rolename = [securityadmin];'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        
        SET @sql = 'use ' + @ThisDatabase + ';
            EXEC sp_droprolemember [db_securityadmin], ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ';'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    END

    -- Declare cursor, Loop through the RoleID table and add the appropriate security roles
    DECLARE @RoleName varchar(50), @RoleInList bit

    PRINT 'Iterating through roles to check/add'
    DECLARE csr CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
    FOR SELECT lur.RoleName
        , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblRoleIDs urids WHERE urids.RoleID = lur.UserRoleID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RoleInList
    FROM [list].[UserRoles] lur 

    OPEN csr
    -- Fetch the first row of the cursor and assign its values into variables
    FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @RoleName, @RoleInList
    -- perform action whilst a row was found
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @RoleInList = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblDbRoles WHERE RoleName = @RoleName) --Add role if it's not already there
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Adding database role' + QUOTENAME(@RoleName)
            SET @sql = 'use ' + @ThisDatabase + ';
                EXEC sp_addrolemember ' + QUOTENAME(@RoleName) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ';'
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        END

        IF @RoleInList = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblDbRoles WHERE RoleName = @RoleName) --Delete role if it exists but isn't in the list
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Dropping database role' + QUOTENAME(@RoleName)
            SET @sql = 'use ' + @ThisDatabase + ';
                EXEC sp_droprolemember ' + QUOTENAME(@RoleName) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ';'
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        END

        IF @RoleName = 'udr_UserAdmin'
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Checking for SecurityAdmin role'
            -- SET @sql = 'use master;'
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT RoleName FROM @TblServerRoles WHERE RoleName = 'securityadmin')
            --in addition to adding user to the udr_UserAdmin role (done in the previous step), also give permission to create users and logins
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Adding SecurityAdmin role'
                SET @sql = 'use master;EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ', @rolename = [securityadmin];'
                EXEC sp_executesql @sql
                
                PRINT 'Adding db_SecurityAdmin role'
                SET @sql = 'use ' + @ThisDatabase + ';
                    EXEC sp_addrolemember [db_securityadmin], ' + QUOTENAME(@UserLogin) + ';'
                EXEC sp_executesql @sql
            END
        END

        -- get next row of cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO @RoleName, @RoleInList
    END
    -- Close the cursor to release locks
    CLOSE csr 
    -- Free memory used by cursor
    DEALLOCATE csr 

    PRINT 'Selecting server roles'
    SELECT CAST(r.name AS varchar(128)) AS RoleName
    FROM master.sys.server_principals r
    INNER JOIN master.sys.server_role_members rm ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id AND r.type = 'R'
    INNER JOIN master.sys.server_principals m ON m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
    WHERE m.name = @UserLogin

    PRINT 'Selecting database roles'
    SELECT r.[name] AS RoleName
    FROM sys.database_principals r 
    INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members rm ON rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals m ON rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
    WHERE m.[name] = @UserLogin
END
```

When I run the following code as myself (I'm the server admin), it runs without issue:

```
USE [TheDatabase]
GO

DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @StaffID int
DECLARE @UserLogin varchar(100)
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(50)
DECLARE @LastName varchar(50)
DECLARE @RoleIDs varchar(50)
DECLARE @IsActive bit

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [usradm].[udp_AddUpdateUser] 
   10
  ,'thedomain\theusername'
  ,'TheFirstName'
  ,'TheLastName'
  ,''
  ,0
GO
```

But when I created a user using this code and gave them UserAdmin permissions, it did successfully set them up in these roles:
SERVER: securityadmin
Database: udr_UserAdmin

...but when I run the above code with "EXECUTE AS USER = [that other user with securityadmin permissions]"...

...I get the following output:

```
Checking UserLogin
Creating UserLogin
use master;
            CREATE LOGIN [thedomain\theusername] FROM WINDOWS WITH  
            DEFAULT_DATABASE = [TheDatabase],
            DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english];
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Checking database user
Creating database user
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Adding record to Staff table
Adding record to StaffUsernames
Parsing @RoleIDs into table
Adding StaffRoles
Deleting StaffRoles not passed
Loading existing server roles
Loading existing database roles
Iterating through roles to check/add
Checking for SecurityAdmin role
Adding SecurityAdmin role
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot alter the server role 'securityadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Adding db_SecurityAdmin role
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot alter the role 'db_securityadmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Selecting server roles
Selecting database roles

Completion time: 2023-03-06T20:55:06.9458622-06:00
```

What am I missing?

Running SQL Server Standard 2019. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can't do `use` like that, you need to instead do something like `DECLARE @proc NVARCHAR(1000) = @ThisDatabase + N'.sys.sp_executesql'; EXEC @proc .....`

Comment: Tagging onto the comment by @Charlieface - I don't think you need to `use` anything because create login will work from the context of a user database. What I think the issue is is that securityadmin is not sufficient to manage users. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16), "...database-level permissions if they have access to a database.". In some limited testing, I was able to create a user by granting `connect any database` and `alter any database` to a login with securityadmin.

Comment: All that said, if the required permissions feel like too much, consider [module signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver16) which allows elevated permissions only within the context of this particular stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks! I'm giving your suggestions a shot, and will update after I get the certificate signing down. :)

Comment: Other notes: object names should be `sysname` (alias for `nvarchar(128)`) not `varchar(50)`. Instead of the deprecated `sp_dropsrvrolemember` etc procedures, you should use `ALTER SERVER ROLE`.

Comment: Thanks again. :) I implemented the suggestions until now, and everything seems to be working much better.I'll look into ALTER SERVER ROLE. Regarding varchar(50)... that's how I store the names of the roles to add in my list.UserRoles table (since I created the database roles, I have control over how many characters it is). It doesn't seem to break anything, and changing the table at this point probably would break stuff, and I'm working on a deadline. :D

Comment: ...actually, I just remembered, after implementing Ben's suggestion to use module signing, I got rid of the sp_addsrvrolemember and sp_dropsrvrolemember code altogether. Members of the udr_UserAdmin role no longer need securityadmin permissions, because the procedure itself is signed with a certificate attached to a user with securityadmin permissions.